# Ionic - AngularJS: calling methods via template outside of Controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-controller, angular-template

So, here's a sample code:

```
<div ng-controller="MyControllerOne">
    <span ng-click="foobar()">Click Me!</span>
</div>
```

Can I, from that template, without changing controller, call the function *foobar()* in *MyControllerTwo*:

```
.controller('MyControllerOne', function($scope) {
    //some code
})
.controller('MyControllerTwo', function($scope) {
    // method I wanna call
    function foobar(){
    }
})
```

Comment: You could make use of services here. Add a method in the service that manipulates any persistent data, which should also be in your service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not the prettiest solution, it is technically possible...ish.

If you update your HTML to:

```
<div ng-controller="MyControllerOne">
    <span ng-controller="MyControllerTwo as mct" ng-click="mct.foobar()">Click Me!</span>
</div>
```

Then you should get your expected results.

Answer (score 1):

You can call method which is in another controller from the template by injecting '$controller' service in the controller. Below is the demo and code.

You can see demo here: http://plnkr.co/edit/oBEKxamgJv0uDVsJJwth?p=preview

HTML:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-click="fooBar()">Click Me!</div>
  </body>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $controller) {
  $controller('SubCtrl', {$scope: $scope});
});

app.controller('SubCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.fooBar = function() {
    alert('second controller');
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty old question, but if any one is still looking for an alternative answer ...
It should be possible to use $emit or $broadcast.

Like from ControllerOne :

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('callToFoobat',{});
```

And then from ControllerTwo :

```
$scope.$on('callToFoobat', function(){ 
    // whatever you want, so why not a call to foobar 
})
```

Just a rough solution. Might be more elegant or lighter than just $rootScope.$broadcast. And maybe think about stoping propagation whenever needed.